# Программа работающей на динамическом сборе данных

Tags: c++

Код ниже — это скелет программы, работающей на динамическом сборе данных. Идея состоит в том, чтобы использовать структуру, содержащую два поля: первое хранит количество элементов в коллекциях, а второе — фактическую коллекцию (динамически размещаемый вектор целых чисел). Как видите, коллекция заполнена необходимым количеством псевдослучайных данных.
К сожалению, программа требует завершения, как самая важная функция.

Вот что я ожидаю от функции:

1. Eсли коллекция пуста, ей следует выделить одноэлементный вектор и сохранить в ней новое значение.
2. Eсли коллекция не пустая, ей следует выделить новый вектор, длина которого на один больше, чем у текущего вектора, затем скопировать все элементы из старого вектора в новый, добавить новое значение в новый вектор и, наконец, освободить старый вектор.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Collection {
    int elno;
    int *elements;
};
void AddToCollection(Collection &col, int element) {
    //the first part of the funtion
    if (col.elno==0){
        col.elements= new int[1];
        col.elements[0]= element;
    }
    //this is the second part but i do not know how to do it.
    //Please  help me to complete***************
    else {
        int *temp;
        temp = new[];
    }
}

void PrintCollection(Collection col) {
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < col.elno; i++)
        cout << col.elements[i] << " ";
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
int main(void) {
    Collection collection = { 0, NULL };
    int elems;
    cout << "How many elements? ";
    cin >> elems;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < elems; i++)
        AddToCollection(collection, rand() % 100 + 1);
    PrintCollection(collection);
    delete[] collection.elements;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваша ошибка с выделением памяти под массив. Но... у вас есть структура  Collection, и хотя эта структура вовсе и не является коллекцией, но она имеет указатель на такую же структуру. Используйте его для добавления нового элемента, и не нужен никакой массив чисел. А если связи не нужны, то нужен массив  Collection, а не массив чисел.

Comment: Вы же во 2-м пункте написали как это сделать: `temp = new int[col.elno + 1]` => поэлементное копирование и запись в конец нового эл-та => `delete` старый => `col.elements` = новый. И не забыть увеличить `elno` на 1 (и в ветке `if (col.elno == 0)` тоже)